# How to add custom TabBarItem to Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I am using the Storyboard in XCode to design my Views. Also im using the `Tab Bar Controller` in the editor, but i cannot seem to figure out how i can add a custom item which i can use for `UIPopoverController`.

Is it possible or do i have to create this controller programmatically and add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apple documentation states that you shouldn't subclass UITabBarController, however, you could use a custom implementation like one of the ones found here:

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/altabbarcontroller

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/center-button-in-tab-bar

EDIT: This website appear to have exactly what you want - http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

Comment: I have no problems with the standard tab bar, and it actually works quite fine. The issue is only that i want to pop an extra item in the tab bar for UIPopoverController purpose. Is it necessary to make a custom tab bar?